# Why is the pressure different at these points?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, gas

I'm controlling a double-sided cylinder and as shown in the illustration below.  When the compressor pushes the air into one side of the cylinder (and the other side opens its drain output) the piston moves to the right:

[image: Illustration of the system]

But during the process the pressure reading shown by valve-2 is always much smaller than valve-1. I couldn't find a leakage. What phenomenon causes that difference in this case?

(Valve-2 is a valve that is supposed to show the pressure inside the cylinder)

Comment: May be a language issue, but valves are not pressure indicators. Now, if pressure gauge at 2 is close to the piston, and the connecting pipe is small, you may have a conductance issue with a pressure drop between 1 and 2.

Comment: But what do the valves indicate? So the reason Valve2 shows less is the drop across the pipes?

Comment: Valves don’t indicate anything. Pressure gauges do. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry I meant gauges because they are attached on valves. The valve in my drawing represents both valve and its gauge